# How to move axes to the middle of QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qtgui, qcustomplot

By default `QCPAxisRect` has four axes which arrange in a rectangle. I want a plus type axis at the the center of `QCustomPlot`. How can I do that?

Comment: just saw this on the QCP forum, looking for the same answer... dont know if it will be possible though

Comment: Hmm iv had a thought on this, if there is a way that you change where the view is looking you could set it to look at 0,0 in the middle of the screen and change the style of the 0 line, and maybe add some text items or something so they look more like axis.

i know this isnt a complete solution but im going to give it a try now because it could do the trick for now at least

Comment: @AngryDuck http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/support/forum/86

Comment: thanks dude! works exactly as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small hack to which can be used as a workaround:
http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/support/forum/86